# terraform AWS: instancia sin salida a Internet aun con egress configurado

Tags: aws, terraform

Estoy aprendiendo AWS + terraform; pero la conectividad de mi instancia (`t2.micro`, *ami* `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-20230325`) no es correcta.

He creado 2 grupos de seguridad, 1 para permitir el acceso mediante `SSH` (que funciona bien) y otro para permitir todos las conexiones `TCP` salientes.

Este último ... pues como que no quiere funcionar. Aun siguiendo [la documentación oficial de `terraform`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group), la instancia no puede actualizar la BBDD de paquetes disponibles.

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-3"
    shared_credentials_files = [ "Ruta-al-archivo-credentials" ]
    profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "grupo_ssh" {
    name = "Permitir entrada SSH"
    ingress {
        cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
        description = "Acceso acceso SSH"
        from_port = 22
        to_port = 22
        protocol = "TCP"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "grupo_aptget" {
    name = "Permitir instalacion paquetes"
    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port = 0
        protocol = "TCP"
        cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
        ipv6_cidr_blocks = [ "::/0" ]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "mi_servidor" {
    ami = "ami-05e8e219ac7e82eba"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.grupo_ssh.id, aws_security_group.grupo_aptget.id ]
}
```

Conectado a la instancia como usuario `root` y ejecutando

```
apt-get update
```

muestra errores de conexión:

> Could not connect to eu-west-3.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.253.229.19), connection timed out
> ...
> ...

Aparentemente, la resolución DNS funciona correcto (se muestra la IP *objetivo*), pero las conexiones HTTP (las usadas por el sistema de paquetes, puerto 80) no reciben respuesta.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que apt-get usa HTTP, HTTPS y FTP, así que debería bastar con decirle que salga usando TCP. Sin embargo, podrías probar abriendo las opciones de protocolo un poco.

```
egress {
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Lo otro es que revises [en la VPC correspondiente](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html), las rutas existentes. Es posible que la EC2 esté definida pero la VPC tenga una tabla de rutas que no lo permita.

Comment: Es correcto, usando `"-1"` funciona ... lo cual me resulta **extremadamente curioso**, porque las conexiones son HTTP por el puerto 80 ... vamos, TCP *corriente y moliente* ...

Comment: @Trauma debe ser que _algo más hace_ antes de establecer la conexión TCP. Toca chismearlo en detalle de pura curiosidad :)

Comment: jejeje ... ya le he puesto `tcpdump` y estoy *cacharreando* ... aunque de momento, no veo el porqué ... son todo conexiones al puerto 80 :-/